# How to get environment variable ProgramFiles(x86) in Ant

Tags: ant, environment-variables, program-files

I can get `%ProgramFiles%` in Ant with `${env.PROGRAMFILES}`. But I can't figure out how to get `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `${env.ProgramFiles(x86)}`. The variable is case-sensitive in a way that is inconsistent with env.PROGRAMFILES.

```
[echo] env.ProgramFiles(x86) == C:\Program Files (x86)
[echo] env.PROGRAMFILES(x86) == ${env.PROGRAMFILES(x86)}
[echo] env.ProgramFiles      == ${env.ProgramFiles}
[echo] env.PROGRAMFILES      == C:\Program Files
```

Comment: For me the two variable cases where not inconsistent: they are env.ProgramFiles and env.ProgramFiles(x86). Maybe something changed in a newer ant? I have ant 1.9.4.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `${env.PROGRAMFILES(x86)}` ? (See [how to get program files x86 env variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594066/how-to-get-program-files-x86-env-variable))

Apologies, I don't have a windows machine to test this one.

If this doesn't work I'd suggest adding the following property task in your build:

```
<property environment="env"/>
```

And run ANT in debug mode to see the values set:

```
 ant -d
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Mark. That syntax doesn't work; however, in the course of mis-typing it, I found that ${env.ProgramFiles(x86)} works. It's an odd thing -- ${env.PROGRAMFILES} works but ${env.ProgramFiles} does not. So there's some inconsistency in the syntax here. Thanks for getting me to the solution!