# How to install mysql from batch file?

Tags: mysql

I am working on java desktop application in which i use MYSQL database, but i have a problem , i want to embed MYSQL database, for this i want a script to install the MYSQL, i need Help to install MYSQL from batch file (windows).

i am using this script

```
@echo off
echo Installing MySQL Server. Please wait...

msiexec /i "mysql-installer-community-5.6.14.0.msi" /qn

echo Configurating MySQL Server...

"%ProgramFiles%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe" 
-i -q ServiceName=MySQL RootPassword=mysql ServerType=DEVELOPER 
DatabaseType=MYISAM Port=3306 Charset=utf8

echo Installation was successfully
```

i get the error,"The system cannot find the path specified".

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running the batchfile from the folder where mysql installer file is?

Comment: yes the batch file is in same folder.

Comment: Then %ProgramFiles% probably points to wrong directory. On my server, the Mysql folder for the server 5.6 is located in C:\Program Files\ , then MySQL also has a folder C:\Program Files x86\ - Here workbench and other odbc connectors are stored. Can you confirm that the %ProgramFiles% variables point to the correct folder?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that `%ProgramFiles%` is pointing to the wrong folder.

Try `@echo %ProgramFiles%` from a file to see what folder it is looking in. You have to make sure that it is not in the `Program Files x86` folder.

I found this link also, maybe it can help you out?

Source: [how to get program files x86 env variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594066/how-to-get-program-files-x86-env-variable)

EDIT

To be just sure, can you try it with the full path instead of the system variable?

Like this,

```
@echo off
echo Installing MySQL Server. Please wait...

msiexec /i "mysql-installer-community-5.6.14.0.msi" /qn

echo Configurating MySQL Server...

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe" 
-i -q ServiceName=MySQL RootPassword=mysql ServerType=DEVELOPER 
DatabaseType=MYISAM Port=3306 Charset=utf8

echo Installation was successfully
```

or even

```
@echo off
echo Installing MySQL Server. Please wait...

msiexec /i "mysql-installer-community-5.6.14.0.msi" /qn

echo Configurating MySQL Server...
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\" <-- set folder first, then run executeable
mysqlinstanceconfig.exe
-i -q ServiceName=MySQL RootPassword=mysql ServerType=DEVELOPER 
DatabaseType=MYISAM Port=3306 Charset=utf8

echo Installation was successfully
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I am working on 32-bit windows, there is only one Program Files folder.

Comment: I have managed to resolve the problem, the problem is that the msi file i was using did not create "MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6" folder in Program Files,so that system can not find the path specified.I was using the wrong .msi file ,now i am using "mysql-5.1.68-win32.msi" I have changed this command "msiexec /i "mysql-5.1.68-win32" /qn" to "msiexec /i "mysql-5.1.68-win32" /qb" ,it will install the mysql into Program Files and the system now did find the path to "\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe" and sets the mysql configuration.

Answer (score 2):

### My batch file complete:

@echo off

cls

echo ==========================================

echo MySQL Server - Installation - v.17/03/2014

echo ==========================================

echo .

echo .

rem ------------------------------------------------

echo Installing. Wait ...

msiexec /i "mysql-5.5.28-win32.msi" /qn

echo Done.

rem ------------------------------------------------

echo .

echo .

rem ------------------------------------------------

echo Configurating. Waiting ...

cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\" 

mysqlinstanceconfig.exe -i -q ServiceName=MySQL RootPassword=mypassword ServerType=DEVELOPER DatabaseType=INODB Port=myport Charset=utf8

echo Done.

rem ------------------------------------------------

echo .

echo .

rem ------------------------------------------------

echo Creating access to user. Waiting ...

cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\" 

mysql -uroot -pmypassword --execute="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;"

mysql -uroot -pmypassword --execute="FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"

echo Done.

rem ------------------------------------------------

echo .

echo .

echo Installation ready.

echo .

echo .

pause