# Bat file doesn't executed as expected when executed by java

Tags: java, mysql, batch-file

I have written a bat file to install mysql. It works well when executing by double clicking but when it executed by java program it prompted and vanishes, nothing happens. Any suggestions?

this is my bat file:

```
set cur=%cd%
set pro=%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%
pause
if exist "%pro%"  goto yes86
set pro=%PROGRAMFILES%

:yes86
if exist "%pro%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql.exe" goto yesmysql

msiexec /i "mysql-5.5.13.msi" /passive INSTALLDIR="%pro%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5"

cd /d %pro%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin

MySQLInstanceConfig.exe -i -q "-lC:\mysql_install_log.txt" "-nMySQL Server 5.5" "-       p%pro%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5" -v5.5.13 "-t%pro%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my-template.ini" "-c%pro%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini" ServerType=DEVELOPMENT DatabaseType=MIXED ConnectionUsage=OLTP Port=3306 ServiceName=Mysql Charset=utf8 RootPassword=abc
:yesmysql
```

this is my java code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start MySQL.bat");
```

Comment: It will helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118746/how-to-install-mysql-from-batch-file

Comment: my bat files runs perfectly by itself and installs mysql, but not with java program, its the problem I am having.

Comment: When launching commands through ... (say java in your use case) never be confident in environment variables. Use full paths for all commands (at least `MySQLInstanceConfig`) and spy (`echo "%pro%" > c:\accessible\path\spy.txt`) the other environment variables you use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your bat file works outside of Java, just change this

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start MySQL.bat");
```

to

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("MySQL.bat");
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but no luck. when I add pause in batch file it shows `system cannot find path specified`.

Comment: Then specify the path to `c:/mypath/mysql.bat` (windows isn't case sensitive on file names).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try this one :

```
List cmdAndArgs = Arrays.asList({"cmd", "/c", "MYSQL.bat"});
File dir = new File("C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/bin/bat");

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdAndArgs);
pb.directory(new File(dir));
Process p = pb.start();
```