# Batch File Copying

Tags: file, batch-file, copy, move

I am trying to copy a file from the C:\ drive to the steam directory using this

copy "C:\CSS.zip"  "C:\%ProgramFiles86%\Steam\CSS.zip"

but it always makes a new folder and places the file in a new folder called %ProgramFiles86% but i want it to go in the actual Program Files (x86)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Your environment variable is incorrect check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594066/how-to-get-program-files-x86-env-variable

Comment: `copy C:\CSS.zip "%programfiles(x86)%\CSS.zip"`

Comment: yes, `%programfiles(x86)%` ==> `C:\Program Files (x86)`

Comment: what does `set program` say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using the program files path correctly. Your code should be this:

```
copy C:\CSS.zip "%programfiles(x86)%\CSS.zip"
```