# windows/System32 or windows/SysWOW64

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a 32 bit application.
How correctly (officially) to find out which folder to install the application, depending on the bit depth of the OS?
Are there any winapi commands that would give out the correct path, if i indicating that the application is 32 bit.

`windows/System32` or `windows/SysWOW64`?

In general, how correctly to do, if i'm not want to check if one of this folder exist?

Minimum supported client needed - `Windows XP`.

Comment: Install in neither of those directories

Answer (score 2):

You should call [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx) supplying `FOLDERID_ProgramFiles` folder id. It will retrieve correct directory for applications. If you still want to install into system32 (though typical applications should not do it), then you can call it with `FOLDERID_SystemX86`.

Comment: `Minimum supported client
Windows Vista [desktop apps only]`
What about xp?

Comment: You can try checking `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` environment variable as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594066/how-to-get-program-files-x86-env-variable).

Comment: There is the old function [SHGetFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx) for XP.

Comment: Thank yo guys.  In fact, I want to know it through RPC. I know, this is the topic of another question, but nevertheless ... For example: https://web.archive.org/web/20160403140939/http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/articles/win_net_srv/msrpc_winreg.html

Comment: @Andreyua What matters is less what you actually want, but what you ask. This question doesn't specify RPC and so this question is not about RPC. If you asked the wrong question, tough. You should know well enough by now how to ask.